# Importing split csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file that looks like:

```
Point            Site Energy Savings (%/yr) Annualized Energy Related Costs ($/yr)
Optimal Point 0        0                        1822.880005
Optimal Point 1        14.39999962              1608.069946
Optimal Point 2        20.65999985              1596.76001
Optimal Point 3        26.05999947              1639.98999
Optimal Point 4        34.54999924              1786.359985


Point            Site Energy Savings (%/yr) Annualized Energy Related Costs ($/yr)
Reference              0                        1822.880005
Iter 1, Pt 1           6.929999828              1818.089966
Iter 1, Pt 2           8.170000076              1863.180054
Iter 1, Pt 3           4.159999847              1845.390015
```

And I am trying to read it into R to plot the 2nd and 3rd column in a scatterplot, however read.csv is getting confused because of the double header. Any idea how to read it into R skipping the second header?

I would like the following to show in R:

```
Point                Site Energy Savings (%/yr) Annualized Energy Related Costs ($/yr)
Optimal Point 0      0                           1822.880005
Optimal Point 1      14.39999962                 1608.069946
Optimal Point 2      20.65999985                 1596.76001
Optimal Point 3      26.05999947                 1639.98999
Reference            0                           1822.880005
Iter 1, Pt 1         6.929999828                 1818.089966
Iter 1, Pt 2         8.170000076                 1863.180054
Iter 1, Pt 3         4.159999847                 1845.390015
```

Comment: Where are the commas? You did say csv file. It might be a good idea to use a github gist to show the exact file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
# read in first 5 rows only
a <- read.csv(file, nrows=5, header=TRUE) 

# read in the last rows skipping the first 5 row data set 
b <- read.csv(file, skip=6, header=TRUE)   

rbind(a,b) # put them back together
```